# Youtube video reloading on firefox when CSS attribute overflow changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

View demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/55H7U/26/

Play video in firefox, when CSS overflow attribute is changed the video reloads. This does not occur on any other browser that I have tested. Any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: why isnt the `overflow-y` in the loaded html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to prevent it at the moment if you have to dynamically change the `overflow` value.

Once https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268 is fixed the problem will just go away.